# Undefined element of style in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, compiler-errors, styles

I am building a small sorting visualiser and I am getting this error even though every style property is defined .
My app.js code is here
The error is show at the numbers 1 and 2 (I mentioned 1 and 2 in the comments of code .

```
mergeSort(){
     // mergeSort animation is a different function
     const animations=mergeSortAnimations(this.state.array);
     for(let i=0;i<animations.length;i++){
        //take all the array bars
     const arrayBars=document.getElementsByClassName("array-bar");
     const isColorChange = i % 3 !== 2;
     if(isColorChange){
       const [barOneIdx,barTwoIdx]=animations[i];
       const barOneStyle=arrayBars[barOneIdx].style; // 1
      
       const barTwoStyle =arrayBars[barTwoIdx].style; // 2
       
       const colour = (i%3 === 0)?FIRST_COLOR:SECOND_COLOR ;
       setTimeout(() => {
           barOneStyle.backgroundColor=colour;
           barTwoStyle.backgroundColor=colour;
       },i*3); 
     }else{
         setTimeout(() => {
         const [barOneIdx,newHeight]=animations[i];
          const barOneStyle=arrayBars[barOneIdx].style;
          barOneStyle.height=`${newHeight} px`;
         },i*5);
     }
       
    }
    };
```

and the sorting algorithm is correct and I am new to react js .Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: May you consider removing all code that is unrelated to the issue?

Comment: sorry for that..i edited the question.

Comment: when i comment the barTwoStyle element it doesn't show any error .But i need that statement to show how sorting occurs in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the bug in my code.While the animations array is getting updated in the other function ,it was pushing single value into the pair rather than 2 values.so hence it wasn't able to figure out which part of the bar has to be styled .